# Select values from a date column without consider seconds value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL table which has a `DATETIME column(EndTime)`. From my code I am passing a date and I want to get the date that has an `EndTime` equal to that date. I used

```
SELECT MAX([EndTime]) FROM [dbo].[Table]  where [EndTime]=@date
```

What I want is if I pass `2013-06-14 10:35` to the query it should return all the records in this time. But due to the seconds value in the table it returns only the value which has `2013-06-14 10:35:000`. How can I ignore the seconds part in the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try something like

```
SELECT MAX([EndTime]) 
FROM [dbo].[Table]  
where [EndTime]>=@date
AND [EndTime]<DATEADD(minute,1,@date)
```

OR even

```
SELECT MAX([EndTime]) 
FROM [dbo].[Table]  
where convert(varchar(16),EndTime,120) = @date
```

Comment: First query: awesome.  Second query: deserves cruel and lonely death. Please remove it, it repugnantly violates best practice

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below to remove seconds

```
SELECT MAX([EndTime]) 
FROM [dbo].[Table]  
where   DATEadd(ss,-datepart(ss,EndTime),EndTime) = @date
```

Comment: Good for suggesting date math but not sargable, so I could not recommend it.